# How to read a text file of set of values in python and print the values

Tags: python, file, text

[image]

I have a text file and set of values representing different objects. the values for each object is seperated by white space. I need to store the values in a list and find mean for each object.(each object has different d1, d2, d3 values).

Comment: And anything you have tried so far?

Comment: Is it normal to have the three blocs of data that are exactly the same ?

Comment: i just gave some random values. I want to calculate first block d1 value mean. similarly for all three blocks

Answer (score 1):

You question is a bit unclear, but the solution for your problem might be this

```
import re

regex = re.compile('d1 : (\d+) d2 : (\d+) d3: (\d+)')

with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    content = file.readlines()

i = 0
objects = {}
for pos, line in enumerate(content):
    match = regex.match(line)

    if not match:
        continue
    if pos % 6 == 0:
        i += 3
        if i > 3:
            objects[f'{i-6}-mean'] =  sum(objects[f'{i-6}']) / len(objects[f'{i-6}'])
            objects[f'{i-5}-mean'] =  sum(objects[f'{i-5}']) / len(objects[f'{i-5}'])
            objects[f'{i-4}-mean'] =  sum(objects[f'{i-4}']) / len(objects[f'{i-4}'])
        objects[f'{i-3}'] = []
        objects[f'{i-2}'] = []
        objects[f'{i-1}'] = []

    objects[f'{i-3}'].append(int(match[1]))
    objects[f'{i-2}'].append(int(match[2]))
    objects[f'{i-1}'].append(int(match[3]))

i += 3 
objects[f'{i-6}-mean'] =  sum(objects[f'{i-6}']) / len(objects[f'{i-6}'])
objects[f'{i-5}-mean'] =  sum(objects[f'{i-5}']) / len(objects[f'{i-5}'])
objects[f'{i-4}-mean'] =  sum(objects[f'{i-4}']) / len(objects[f'{i-4}'])

print(objects)
```

Output

```
{'0': [472, 475, 477, 477, 477], '1': [998, 992, 991, 991, 991], '2': [367, 365, 367, 367, 367], '0-mean': 475.6, '1-mean': 992.6, '2-mean': 366.6, '3': [1, 2, 3, 4, 477], '4': [998, 992, 991, 991, 991], '5': [367, 365, 367, 367, 367], '3-mean': 97.4, '4-mean': 992.6, '5-mean': 366.6}
```

If its not, please elaborate on that.

Comment: the first block represents an object. second one represents another object and similarly the third. Now, I want to find the mean value for all the d1 values of an individual object. i.e for first object(first block), mean m1, second object(second block), m2, and similarly m3

Comment: @VBALAJIKASYAP1760367 i adjusted code, it should do what you want

Comment: what if there are more than 5 values for each object